# How do memory addresses work in the Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

What is the schema for C++ memory addresses under the Android NDK? They seem to have changed (become longer) in recent NDKs compared to older NDKs, so I'm trying to understand the original schema as well as how and why they've evolved. Documentation on this topic seems hard to find.

Note that I'm talking about C++ heap memory addresses, not JVM addresses.

Comment: Are you comparing 32-bit to 64-bit? 32 bit pointers are 4 bytes long and 64-bit are 8 bytes.

Comment: No, this is 64 bit in both cases.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Note that Android has been using Address Space Layout Randomization for a long time.

Comment: Our legacy C++ code uses a signed pointer for memory addresses. I have to chop off the high-order bytes to make them work, and it does seem to work fine. Those high order bytes don't seem to be necessary in C++ land. But I'm wondering what they're for, just so I know.  So for example if the address is b400 007c 2ba7 3ac0 then I change it to 0000 007c 2ba7 3ac0 to fit the legacy pointer size. And it works, the C++ code runs fine. Though it doesn't seem like it should.